# Mojo reloading all Maven poms

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

In Maven `3.3.9` how can I reload all projects, my Mojo switches Git branch so needs to reload poms afterward before proceeding. Is there a utility or Guice option to re-create/re-inject MavenSession?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? What is the purpose of that? Are you in a plugin?

Comment: My Mojo switches Git Branch. The pom files change when the branch changes so I'll need to reload. Even if there was a hacky way to achieve this...